# Creating a notification and storing lists of input in a box

Tags: php, html

```
<?php

    session_start();


    function submitform()
    {
        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            notify('positive','hello'.$_POST['name']);
        }
    }

    function notify($type = 'neutral', $message = 'Hello')
    {
        $_SESSION['notify']['type'] = $type;
        $_SESSION['notify']['message'] = $message;

    }

    function notifcation()
    {
        if(isset($_SESSION['notify']))
        {
            $type = $_SESSION['notify']['type'];
            $message = $_SESSION['notify']['message'];

            $html = '<div class="notify'.$type.'">'.$message.'</div>';


            echo $html;
        }
    }

    ?>
```

test.php

```
<?php require 'functions.php' ?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Notification bar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="" />
</head> 
<body>

    <div id="container">

    <?php notification(); ?>  //error

        <h1>Test</h1>
        <h2>Notifcation</h2>

        <form action="<?php submitForm(); ?>" method="post">

            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />

            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Send" />

        </form>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I am creating a notification for my clothing website and where if the admin account creates a new product, it will show in a box (homepage) of the new entity. So I have created an input, where it will output what was written in the form, but in order to show it in my homepage, how would I created a storage box containing a history of products added, because my output right now only shows when I put a text and press enter and only after another text is inserted.

Comment: You'd need a database for this - as I assume you're wanting to show a global alert to other users?

Comment: Ah yes, I have set up the database, so I was just running php code for the time being

Comment: You can prepend the info to a .dat file and use file_get_contents() to render wherever.

Comment: If you have a DB and connection all sorted  - create a notifications table with an ID as the Primary Key and then `type` and `message` columns. Whenever you post the form, have it save to the table. Then simple query your table to extract the most recent entries (by ID). Or... go the oldschool way and write to a file as someone suggested above ;)